# How to get Model class object values while typeCasting it in nsarray?

Tags: ios, core-data, casting

I typeCast `Product`(name of a model class where objects is created) class with array (object of NSArray which contains fetched data from database).When I want to set values of project class object into `NSMutableDictionary` i.e `[data setObject:product.prodName forKey:kProductName];` app crashes.

```
entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Product" inManagedObjectContext:appDelegate.managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:entityDescription];
NSSortDescriptor *sd = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"prodId" ascending:NO];
request.sortDescriptors = @[sd];
[request setPredicate: [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"active = %@ AND isDeletedProd = %@",@1,@0]];
_fetchedResultController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:appDelegate.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];

_fetchedResultController.delegate = self;
request.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;

NSError *error;
[_fetchedResultController performFetch:&error];
arrdata = [self.fetchedResultController fetchedObjects];
```

This code i used to fetch data.And then want to typecast it into Product.

```
Product *arrProd = (Product *)arrdata;
```

Then Pass arrProd into json by using method given below.

```
[[ServerSyncUtil sharedInstance] syncProduct:arrProd withHandler:^(BOOL success,NSData *data , NSError *error)
 {


 }];
```

Which all this method..

```
-(void)syncProduct:(Product *)product withHandler:(syncHandler)handler {
    NSMutableArray *products = [NSMutableArray array];
    [products addObject:[self addProduct:product]];
    [self uploadProducts:products withHandler:handler];
}
```

And then addProduct method called.

```
-(NSDictionary *) addProduct:(Product *) product {
    NSMutableDictionary *data = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    NSLog(@"%@",product);
    [data setObject:product.prodName forKey:kProductName];
    [data setObject:product.desc ? product.desc:@"" forKey:kDescription];
    return datal
}
```

Here when want to setObject into  array data app goes crash.

Comment: add some code please.

Comment: `data setObject:product.desc ? product.desc:@"" forKey:kDescription];` gives crash?

Comment: yes it goes crash.Actually i think there is no value in product.prodName.But in product it has value.

Comment: Try putting a dummy value `@"xyz"` instead of `product.prodName`, and see if it still crashes. BTW, what is the crash, please add that too.

Comment: if I put dummy values its working fine.While using product.prodName crashes is                                                                                                      2016-09-12 13:45:57.089 BQ[15363:247379] -[__NSArrayM prodName]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fcb89d60c40
2016-09-12 13:45:57.111 BQ[15363:247379] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM prodName]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fcb89d60c40'

Comment: Add you class Product code too please, `prodName` doesn't exists.

Comment: If i set each value into Product class object like product.prodname,product.Desc.And suppose i get two array data pass into product class then after loop it returns last data.

Answer (score 0):

You already have an array, you don't need to create a new one. You're trying to treat an array as a single object. You even call the variable `arrdata` indicating you know it's an array, but you don't treat it as an array.

Instead use:

```
NSArray *products = [self.fetchedResultController fetchedObjects];
```